# Installation of Unity from NugetStore is not working

Tags: c#, unity-container, nuget-package

I am trying to install Unity version 3.0.1304.1 from from NuGet store and getting following error and my project is setup for .NetFramwork V4.0:

*Could not install package 'Unity 3.0.1304.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

Does anyone has any clue what is wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unity 3.0.1304.1 requires .NET 4.5, you can install an older version of Unity using NuGet that targets .NET 4.0 using this command:

> Install-Package Unity -Version 2.1.505.2

Here's a source for this [info](http://unity.codeplex.com/workitem/12731)

Comment: Sorry for the slightly off-topic question, but why doesn't nuget install the latest available version for one's platform (.NET 4.0) automatically?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but this documentation [page](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.0#Group_dependencies_by_target_frameworks) seems to indicate you can group dependencies by target framework.